# ElasticSearch - Unable to load an index with more than 2.1 B documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I stopped the elasticSearch service and restarted it. Now, one of the indices cannot be loaded. Here's the status of the indeices:

```
yellow open test-index        _taPEhm3ReSwCYjb1Y5hQA 1 1         3        0  7.5kb  7.5kb
yellow open wiki-index-000001 aaZvlpgJSuO43uMGKuyqKw 1 1         0        0   208b   208b
yellow open wiki-index-unique s1tU2HpnStWNobkZjQ7KQA 1 1 118098273 51827014 36.8gb 36.8gb
yellow open corpora-index     ruArLOJoSv6HkKVBv-o1MA 1 1 289045137        0 47.3gb 47.3gb
red    open corpora           -86nIPPwS8K5IOpFYNcXBQ 1 1                                 
yellow open simple_bulk       6N8NCLd5S5qOKf9o6R6YhA 1 1         6        0  9.6kb  9.6kb
yellow open test1             SN8ViALMRNGHkBF7o8-3zw 1 1         2        1  5.3kb  5.3kb
yellow open simple-index      zYctGNhNRGWrnCOYpKHBcQ 1 1         1        0  4.5kb  4.5kb
```

When I look at the log file of the cluster, I find this error:

```
[2020-11-20T23:52:54,498][INFO ][o.e.i.s.IndexShard       ] [ilcompn0] [corpora][0] ignoring recovery of a corrupt translog entry
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number of documents in the index cannot exceed 2147483519
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.reserveOneDoc(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:211) ~[lucene-core-8.6.2.jar:8.6.2 016993b65e393b58246d54e8dd$
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232) ~[lucene-core-8.6.2.jar:8.6.2 016993b65e393b58246d54e8$
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:419) ~[lucene-core-8.6.2.jar:8.6.2 016993b65e393b58246d54e8ddda9f56a453eb0e -$
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1333) ~[lucene-core-8.6.2.jar:8.6.2 016993b65e393b58246d54e8ddda9f56a453eb0e - ivera $
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.softUpdateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1661) ~[lucene-core-8.6.2.jar:8.6.2 016993b65e393b58246d54e8ddda9f56a453eb0e - ive$
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.updateDocs(InternalEngine.java:1260) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.indexIntoLucene(InternalEngine.java:1091) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:935) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:819) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyIndexOperation(IndexShard.java:791) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.applyTranslogOperation(IndexShard.java:1526) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.runTranslogRecovery(IndexShard.java:1557) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.lambda$openEngineAndRecoverFromTranslog$9(IndexShard.java:1605) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.recoverFromTranslogInternal(InternalEngine.java:488) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.recoverFromTranslog(InternalEngine.java:463) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.recoverFromTranslog(InternalEngine.java:125) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.openEngineAndRecoverFromTranslog(IndexShard.java:1610) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecovery.internalRecoverFromStore(StoreRecovery.java:436) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecovery.lambda$recoverFromStore$0(StoreRecovery.java:98) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.completeWith(ActionListener.java:325) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.StoreRecovery.recoverFromStore(StoreRecovery.java:96) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.recoverFromStore(IndexShard.java:1883) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable$2.doRun(ActionRunnable.java:73) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:710) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

Is there any suggestion on how I can recover the index?

Comment: Which version are you running? A shard cannot contain more than Integer.MAX documents. In recent versions, they have added a check to reject the write of a document if that would exceed that limit. In your case, however, it seems that you have a version that didn't have that check and hence allowed you to go above the limit.

Comment: @val: I'm using version 7.9.1. So is there any way to delete some of the documents from the index so I can recover the rest of the indexed documents?

Comment: You have only one shard? What is the size of the index?

Comment: @dadoonet: Yes, I have only one shard and its size is about 700GB.

Comment: @Val: This is the size of another index named "corpora-index" with only 280 M documents. The "corpora" index has more than 2.1 B documents and its size is ~700 GB.

Comment: are your indexer (logstash) are working?

Comment: i think this error mean that you are trying to index more document on this indices

Comment: A check [has been added](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/63627) in 7.10 to prevent that situation. I'm not sure yet how to solve this. Also do you have nested documents as well in your mapping?

Comment: Since the translog is corrupt and the index won't load, what you can try to do is to shut down the node, delete the translog* files in `$ES_HOME/data/nodes/0/indices/corpora/0/translog/translog*` and start the node again. You might lose some unwritten data but at least you can open your index and fix the situation by splitting the index into several shards

Comment: @val in earlier version if you delete translog elasticsearch would not start. you should /elasticsearch-translog truncate in some version. in 7.9 elasticsearch will automatically build new translog file?

Comment: @hamidbayat: I think my logstash is working. Here's the output of checking its status: ● logstash.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: You're right @hamidbayat. Now there's a [tool that can help](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-tool.html): `bin/elastisearch-shard remove-corrupted-data --index corpora --shard-id 0 --truncate-clean-translog`

Comment: @Val: I don't have nested documents in my index

Comment: @user3070752 you are indexing on the billionaire indices. change pipeline config and restart logstash. probably your indices will be recovered. if not do what val suggested. it will work. but if you try index more document on  indices, maybe it become red again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there's a [tool that can help](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-tool.html) with corrupted data:

```
bin/elastisearch-shard remove-corrupted-data --index corpora --shard-id 0 --truncate-clean-translog
```

You will lose all pending operations that haven't been written to the index, but at least you'll be able to open your index and split it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it should work. My problem is that to run this command I need to run it by `elasticsearch` user. I installed elasticsearch via debian package (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/deb.html#deb-repo) it doesn't mention what is the password of `elasticsearch` user. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: you dont need to run with elasticsearch user

Comment: Yes, it needs to be run as the `elasticsearch` user, but it doesn't have any password. `runuser -l elasticsearch -c '...the command...'`

Comment: you could specify the conf directory and it will work. something like this: ES_PATH_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch/ bin/elasticsearch shard .....